# Port Forwarding doesn't seem to reach Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, http, router, port-forwarding

I have an Apache http server running on my computer, listening to port 80. I can access my "hello world" page by visiting `http://localhost/` in my browser. I've also set up a static IP address, so that I can access the same page by visiting `http://192.168.0.35/`

I recently changed apartments/roommates, so I've also switched routers. Before I moved, I was using a Netgear router (I can't remember the exact model), but I was able to access my page via the external IP address, just by forwarding port 80 to my computer. Now I'm on a SMC8014W-G, so I followed [this guide](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/SMC/8014WG-SI/Apache.htm) to set up the forwarding. I also used their [port checker](http://portforward.com/help/portcheck.htm) program to verify whether the ports (80, 443-just-in-case) were being forwarded. According to that program, they are being properly forwarded (and I checked a few random other ports, to make sure it wasn't giving me false positives).

As far as I can tell, I've done everything I need to do to make it so I can access my site from my external IP address, but it's just not working! Have I missed some crucial step? What could be wrong?

Comment: 192.168.0.35 is a private address that will not be routed outside your private network. it used to point to your localhost before you moved, right? Do i understand that correctly?

Comment: To be clear, I still have access to the old router (which will be gone soon), but I no longer have a static IP set up. Within that local network, I find my port number via ipconfig, then just tell the router to forward to that one. It works from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not realized this, but apparently some routers (e.g. mine) don't let you use your external IP address to access your own network. I visited my external address from a different network and was able to see the home page being served by my own server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have the same static IP of 192.168.0.35? It's possible you have a different IP and could be on a different subnet with the new router.

Possibly not a stackoverflow question as well.

Comment: I re-ran ipconfig just to be sure:
In the results I have
   IPv4 Address. : 192.168.0.35
   Subnet Mask . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . : 192.168.0.1
(sorry, I can't seem to make that format the way I want)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking to see if your provider may be blocking the access.  If you go to [GRC](http://www.grc.com/default.htm) and select shields up you can run a portscan of your device remotely.  If the port doesn't show as open, you might try forwarding your server to something like 8080 or 8001 to see if your provider allows that access.

Comment: I followed your advice and ran the portscan, picking the "common ports" option. Out of the results, only port 80 was open. All others were "Stealth."